# How to check for availability of a given Firebase API to avoid FirebaseApiNotAvailableException errors in my log

Tags: android, firebase, android-app-indexing, firebase-app-indexing

I get a lot of silent FirebaseApiNotAvailableException errors in my log saying "AppIndexing.API is not available on this device". It's 2.5k exceptions for only 80 users in the last 7 days according to Crashlytics. I do app indexing totally along the lines of Google's guidebook. Can I add an API check to avoid those errors in my logs?

Comment: Were you able to solve this? What type of device were you using?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I've seen this issue on a number of different devices. So far I've updated the firebase libs in my project to the latest ones and I'll see if it helps.